# jQuery -.on("click") Not Working on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that user can upload a file to the database. Unable to make `.on("click")` event on mobile device. It works fine on pc/laptop and the file is uploaded successful. On mobile, if I click the button, there is no response.

**Codes**

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit_upload", function(){
    var data = new FormData(document.querySelector("#fileInfo"));
    // If I comment below variables, 
    // it works fine on both mobile and computers.
    jab = data.get('jab'),
    kat_doc = data.get('jenis_fail'),
    doc_nama = data.get('nama'); 
    doc = data.get('file').size;

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        type: "POST",                   
        data: data,                     
        contentType: false,         
        cache: false,               
        processData:false,              
        success: function(data)         
        {
            $("#cont").html(data);

            if (!doc_nama) {
                $("#nama-doc").addClass("list-group-item list-group-item-warning");
            }

            if (jab == 0) {
                $("#jab").addClass("list-group-item list-group-item-warning");
            }

            if (kat_doc == 0) {
                $("#kat-doc").addClass("list-group-item list-group-item-warning");
            }

            if (!doc) {
                $("#doc").addClass("list-group-item list-group-item-warning");
            }

            $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: "static"});
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#myInput').focus();
            });

        }
    });

});
```

**Note:** If I comment the variables `jab/kat_doc/doc_nama/doc`, it trigger the click event.

How do I want it to work with the variables?

Comment: I'm not saying this is the problem, but why are your `jab`, etc., variables global?

Comment: what if you switch your commas to semicolons on lines 5-6?

Comment: On `tap` or on `touchstart` ?? Hey think mobile events! No mouse on a cell phone.

Comment: @kman already tried that but still the same.

Comment: @nnnnnn make it as global just in case I need to use it again on other function.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console when you have those lines uncommented?

Comment: @kman from the pc that I check, there is no error.

Comment: at the moment, my solution is to make the validation in `php`

Comment: are you sure the FormData API is supported on the mobile browser you're using?  since you can't get to console, could you try alert()'ing the values or something just to see if you're actually getting valid data back from the data.get() calls?  [Compatibility reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility).  Looks pretty limited on mobile.

Comment: Miss out to read that part! I think that is the main reason I am unable to get it via javascript

Answer (score 11):

Think mobile a second...
There is no mouse on a cell phone or tablet.

`click` is definitely a mouse event.

Try adding those events to you handler:
*([Touch event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events))*

```
$(document).on("click tap touchstart", "#submit_upload", function(){
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I tried to replace that earlier but still no response. If comment the variables, it trigger the event.

Comment: Cache? is this script in an external .js file?

Comment: yap, it's on a different file.

Comment: ok... a trick of mine... To avoid caching. Let say `<script src="path"></script>` is cached... Then `<script src="path?v=<?php echo rand(1,999999); ?>"></script>` can't be cached. You use Ajax, so I assume you are confortable whith PHP. ;)

Comment: Click events *are* triggered on phones and tablets even without a mouse. (Incidentally, they can also be triggered from the keyboard in desktop browsers, at least on anchors and form elements.) Note that the question says the code works if certain lines are commented out, so the click handler must be getting called in a general sense.

Comment: @nnnnnn mmm... First check. But the comments out shouldn't change anything since `data` is used as post data for Ajax... No matter what.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks for the tips. I'm using PHP

Comment: Just remove those on production site versions ;)

Comment: brilliant, just what I needed for Android users, click seems fine on iOS but failed on droids... added tap and touchstart and now working. thanks @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 2):

change the first line of your function to below, and it should work:

```
     $(document).on('click touchstart', '#submit_upload', function(){
```

Or give a try to this,

```
     $(document).on('click touchstart tap', '#submit_upload', function(){
```

Comment: nobody giving upvote?

Comment: because it does not work....

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$('#submit_upload').on('click', function(){...});
```

Comment: Why would that make any difference?